# Spring Kafka: Poll for new messages instead of being notified using `onMessage`

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka in my project as it seemed a natural choice in a Spring based project to consume Kafka messages. To consume messages, I can make use of the `MessageListener` interface. Spring Kafka internally takes care to invoke my `onMessage` method for each new message.

However, in my setting I prefer to explicitly poll for new messages and work on them sequentially (which will take a few seconds). As a workaround, I might just block inside my `onMessage` implementation, or buffer the messages internally. However, this seems to go against the core idea of Spring Kafka.

Kafka is designed so that consumers have to poll for new messages, which matches my requirements. Is there a way to make use of this "natural" workflow with Spring Kafka?

Should I refrain from using Spring Kafka for this use case?

The [`KafkaConsumer` documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) states:

> For use cases where message processing time varies unpredictably,
>   neither of these options may be sufficient. The recommended way to
>   handle these cases is to move message processing to another thread,
>   which allows the consumer to continue calling poll while the processor
>   is still working. Some care must be taken to ensure that committed
>   offsets do not get ahead of the actual position. Typically, you must
>   disable automatic commits and manually commit processed offsets for
>   records only after the thread has finished handling them (depending on
>   the delivery semantics you need). Note also that you will need to
>   pause the partition so that no new records are received from poll
>   until after thread has finished handling those previously returned.

Related issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/195

Comment: I might use a `AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener` and pause the consumer whenever too many messages piled up.

Comment: If I understand correctly the std framework here does not process messages sequentially even if single partition? or resolved as stated below...?

Answer (score 9):

The issue with having to keep polling the consumer has now been resolved (in 0.10.1.x by [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread)) so that's not an issue any more (as long as you don't exceed the `max.poll.interval.ms`) which is 5 mins by default but can be increased.

However, if you want to poll yourself, you can still use spring-kafka (e.g. to get the Spring Boot auto configuration goodness if you are using Boot), but you can get a `Consumer` from the `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` and `poll()` it directly.

Comment: These are valid workarounds, and you earned the upvote. However, I still see an issue in how Spring Kafka should be used (as a consumer), as the "push" model is enforced for a "pull" technology. I guess this is by design, but in my case this makes Spring Kafka weird/unusable.

Comment: As I said, the push model not __"enforced"__ at all, you can simply use `consumer.poll()` directly. If there's something more you expect from the framework, please open a GitHub issue with the suggestion.

Comment: Any example as to how to get DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory injected when using application.properties file for autoconfiguration in spring boot

Comment: You should ask a new question rather than commenting on an existing answer; you can simply auto wire the factory just like any bean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it. This is in the context of an integration test configuration class, which I load in my JUnit with:

```
@Import(IntegrationTestConfiguration.class)
```

In my Test class I have the following:

```
@Autowired
Consumer<String, String> consumer;
```

In my test configuration class, I have:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<String, String> consumer() {
    String bootstrapAddress = "server:port";       // fix this 
    String groupId = "my.group";                   // fix this.
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    ConsumerFactory<String, String> fact = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    
    // Create the consumer, subscribe to the topic
    Consumer<String, String> consumer = fact.createConsumer();
    String topic = "my.topic";                     // fix this.
    List<String> topics = new ArrayList<String>();
    topics.add(topic);
    consumer.subscribe(topics);
    return consumer;
}
```

Finally, in my test, I do:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    // Do stuff that will publish a message to Kafka

    // Repeat a number of times untill you get the message you want...
    // Or you give up  
    Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds(2);
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(d);


}
```