# Is there a way to do a Kafka poll using spring-kafka - which retrives the list of new messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I would like to know if there is some option in `spring-kafka` which will grab all the new messages to a list.

For example, if i am listening for `Message` object, I want to get the `List<Message>` since the last poll. Something like :

```
@KafkaListener(poll-interval=1000, topics = "${kafka.topic}", containerFactory = "objectListListenerContainerFactory", )
public void messageListener(List<Message> messages) {
    log.info("Count of new messages since last poll : {}", messages.size());
}
```

I already went through [Spring Kafka: Poll for new messages instead of being notified using `onMessage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306221/spring-kafka-poll-for-new-messages-instead-of-being-notified-using-onmessage). But was not very useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the plain Spring Kafka you can use a `ConsumerFactory` to create a `KafkaConsumer` and then you are on your own to poll records from there whenever it is convenient for your.

Also pay attention that `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` can be *paused* in arbitrary moment to stop polling, but still be connected to the consumer group.

In Spring Integration Kafka extension there is a new `KafkaMessageSource` for this kind of tasks:

```
/**
 * Polled message source for kafka. Only one thread can poll for data (or
 * acknowledge a message) at a time.
 * <p>
 * NOTE: If the application acknowledges messages out of order, the acks
 * will be deferred until all messages prior to the offset are ack'd.
 * If multiple records are retrieved and an earlier offset is requeued, records
 * from the subsequent offsets will be redelivered - even if they were
 * processed successfully. Applications should therefore implement
 * idempotency.
 *
 * @param <K> the key type.
 * @param <V> the value type.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @author Mark Norkin
 * @author Artem Bilan
 *
 * @since 3.0.1
 *
 */
public class KafkaMessageSource<K, V> extends AbstractMessageSource<Object>
implements DisposableBean, Lifecycle {
```

I think we need to consider to document this one in the Spring for Apache Kafka reference manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/_spring_integration.html#si-kafka. So, feel free to raise an issue in the `spring-kafka` project to address that gap.

Comment: Thanks Artem. So at this moment, I assume the best way to do is using KafkaConsumer. I have created an issue in the github. May be this would be a nice feature in future.

Comment: Ok. That might be as a `poll` variant in the `KafkaTrmplate`, but will see... imho Spring Integration does the trick for us already...

Comment: I am going to check Spring Integration as well. :)

Comment: The issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/819